# MacBook brightness decreases even though I've unset this happening "as ambient light changes" & "before display goes to sleep"

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My MacBook's brightness decreases even though I've unset “Automatically adjust brightness as ambient light changes” & “Automatically reduce brightness before display goes to sleep”. It does so within about 2 minutes, in a variety of apps, both when plugged in and unplugged. How can I diagnose and/or fix this?

Comment: Does this coincide with unplugging your Macbook from power? Also what year/model of Macbook is it?

Comment: No, it happens both when plugged in and unplugged, in both cases even for a long period of time, and when my battery is full. It's a 13 inch mid-2012 MacBook Pro - I actually bought it in 2014, it's the old non-Retina model they kept around until then. It's a refurb model so I still get free repairs from Apple.

Comment: Try downloading the caffeine app for Mac (search for it in the Mac App Store), and turn it on so that it'll keep your Mac awake. Then tell me if the problem persists.

Comment: @JohnRamos Easier to just use `caffeinate` from the command line, since it's part of OS X.

Comment: @JMY1000 Sure, but that could sound daunting :).

Comment: @tog22 so, can you try caffeinating your Mac?

Comment: @JohnRamos, I've tried and the problem persists. FYI in case you want _me_ to try to other things, the command line holds no terror, though offering easier alternatives sounds the right approach for SE in general. :)

Comment: Ok :D. What operating system version are you on? If it's El Capitan, go to system preferences, display, automatically adjust brightness and make sure that's off.

Comment: Yep, El Capitan. As I mentioned in my question, I've already unset “Automatically adjust brightness as ambient light changes” & “Automatically reduce brightness before display goes to sleep”. Thanks so much for your help by the way. :)

Comment: My next suggestion would be to sift through all of your apps to make sure there are none that dim/alter the screen (f.lux, iris, others).

Comment: Oh, I do have flux, I'll leave it quit for a few days (and nights - ughh).